# Planar graph drawing

Tags: graph-theory

**how i  determine a face of a planar graph is convex polygon or not..............**

Comment: I can't make sense of this as it stands. A planar graph is
one which can be embedded into the plane. Your question only
makes sense for an actual emebedding in the plane, and I cannot
see any sensible answer save that a face is a convex polygon
if it's a convex polygon. Perhaps a more precise question
is lurking?

Comment: With a protractor, I suppose. You may want to expand on your question to make it easier to know what exactly you are asking. 

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess and say the question is asking whether one can tell if a face of a planar graph is a convex polygon before the graph is drawn with edges as straight line segments. That is, in the beginning, you are given a random drawing where the edges could be curved. Still, I believe the question will be closed unless the OP makes it clear what is being asked.

Comment: Perhaps you are asking for the result of Steinitz's Theorem: Which 
planar graphs are $1-$skeletons of convex polytopes. Answer: The underlying abstract graph has to be $3-$edge connected. Such graphs have 
essentially (up to isotopies and an orientation reversing homeomorphism) only one planar embedding coming from a realization as the $1-$skeleton of a convex polytope.

Comment: I'm going to go with the most naive interpretation: We have $n$ points $(x_i, y_i)$ in the plane, with edges connecting them in cyclic order, and we want to know whether the given $n$-gon is convex. Easy: compute the angle of the ray from $(x_i, y_i)$ to $(x_{i+1}, y_{i+1})$. If these angles are increasing, the polygon is convex.  

Comment: The question has been closed: we simply don't know what you're asking.  If you edit it to provide enough information, precision and context so that we can understand it (and, for bonus points, use proper punctuation and grammar, to the best of your ability), it can be reopened.  

Answer (score 2):

this is not a well defined question. Perhaps you mean that you want to know if a face of a planar embedding of a planar graph is convex ? Note that it's always possible to draw a planar graph so all faces (with the exception of the outer face) are convex

Comment: (I think that this should have been left as a comment, not an answer)